# Update Rows based on JOIN results

Tags: sqlite, sql-update

I can't get the following query to work:

```
UPDATE ISSUE
SET DUE_DATE = DATE(ISSUE.DATE_ADDED,'+90 day')
JOIN CVE on CVE.CVE_ID = ISSUE.CVE_ID
WHERE CVE.CVSS >= 4 AND CVE.CVSS < 9
```

This is because in [`sqlite3`](https://www.sqlite.org/) you can't join in an [`UPDATE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html). What I'm trying to do is set the due date of an issue to be 90 days after the date added if the [`CVE`](https://cve.mitre.org/) associated with the issue is: `greater than or equal to four and less than 9.` Is there an alternative option that I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the rows in a sub-query.

```
UPDATE ISSUE
SET DUE_DATE = DATE(ISSUE.DATE_ADDED,'+90 day')
WHERE ISSUE.CVE_ID IN (
  SELECT ISSUE.CVE_ID
  FROM ISSUE JOIN CVE on CVE.CVE_ID = ISSUE.CVE_ID
  WHERE CVE.CVSS >= 4 AND CVE.CVSS < 9
)
```